# Wave Analytics (Einstein Analytics) Conditional Formatting on Table

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein

I am looking for a way (I haven't found one, and I don't think it is possible) to have conditional formatting on Pivot Table or just any Table within Wave Analytics. E.g. Ability to conditionally color any cell. For example, if a value is lower than a static value or another column's value by specific percentage, then set one color, if lower by another percentage, then set another color.

I tried manipulating the JSON behind a Pivot table, but it was not working. SAQL conditional color is only possible for Number widget.

If anyone had any experience in successfully producing conditional formatting for Wave table-type charts, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the XMD of the dataset (nameofthedataset.xmd.json) to add colors to the relevant member values. Edit the dataset and download the xmd, by default there are no dimensions

{"dataset":{},"dates":[],"derivedDimensions":[],"derivedMeasures":[],"dimensions":[],"measures":[],"organizations":[],"showDetailsDefaultFields":[]}

Then change it according to your requirement,

here is a sample xmd that I have used to change the colors

{"dataset":{},"dates":[],"derivedDimensions":[],"derivedMeasures":[],"dimensions":[{"customActions":[],"field":"Type","label":"Case Type","members":[{"color":"#008FFF","member":"Cer"},{"color":"#B0E0E6","member":"Complaint"},{"color":"#66CDAA","member":"Request"},{"color":"#7CFC00","member":"Other"},{"color":"#FFE4C4","member":"Request2"},{"color":"#FFA07A","member":"Suggestion"},{"color":"#FFBC00","member":"Technical Request"},{"color":"#FFB6C1","member":"Support"}],"recordDisplayFields":[],"salesforceActions":[],"showInExplorer":false}],"measures":[],"organizations":[],"showDetailsDefaultFields":[]}

Comment: Thanks. This is semi-conditional, as it cannot evaluate an arbitrary range comparison, e.g. x < 0, it will only handle static known values for the "member" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Its not currently possible, in an upcoming release they will add conditional formatting to color a cell in based on a logical test condition.